# Meteor margin-bottom with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm using meteor with the bootstrap package. (here is a chunk of code where my problem is)

```
<div class="input-prepend"> 
    <span class="add-on">@</span>
    <input class="span2" id="prependedInput" size="16" type="text">
</div>
```

This is what it ends up looking like

[image]

Upon inspection I find that there is a `margin-bottom : 9px` on the textfield which is causing the problem

Why is this happening, the 9px margin is from the bootstrap css. Meteor adds the `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag anyway so It shouldn't be this. I can fix this by forcing an override of the style but I don't get why the margin-bottom is added into the css file itself. Is there functionality to it?

*EDIT* Its fixed in newer bootstrap. I uppdated bootstrap  manually from 2.0.2

Comment: you're right, can you please post your answer and accept it not to leave the question unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone runs into this problem,

The issue isn't really with meteor its with bootstrap (2.0.2) update it manually by changing the files in /usr/local/meteor/packages with the new bootstrap files (make sure you only update the files which are already there).

Im sure this would be fixed in a newer version of meteor as it updates to the latest bootstrap